# Sharepoint 2010 List item dropdown options cascading

Tags: sharepoint-2010, cascading

I have two dropdowns "Department" and "Employees", Department dropdown cascades Employees dropdown. I need to select all employees from all the departments on option "All". Note: There is no department 'All', it has to select all employees.
Currently using `$().SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns` from http://spcd.codeplex.com/
I have tried CAMQuery but could not achieve.

Answer (score 1):

So far, I have not found a good way to do cascading dropdowns in SharePoint.

Here are a few avenues to hack your way to a solution:

1. SharePoint designer (SPD) has many ways to customize (and break) pages. Not sure that I recommend using SPD since my experiance is that it has caused more side effects than solutions as far as maintainability is concerned.
2. If you have Nintex forms available, there are ways to do psudo-cascading drop downs by editing the input form. Working in an Enterprise setting with SharePoint, this has been an option for me.
3. On the page with the fields, include a webpart with JavaScript that filters the list options based on the choice of the first column. This is what has worked for me in the past but it's been a while so I don't have a specific example for you.

However! There are catches associated with putting JavaScript on the page. Particularly this one:

Here: http://geekswithblogs.net/SoYouKnow/archive/2011/04/06/setting-sharepoint-drop-down-lists-w-jquery---20-items.aspx

and here:
http://www.sharepointboris.net/2009/10/sharepoint-lookup-field-how-does-it-work-and-how-to-add-javascript-event-handler-function-to-it/

[Remember that SharePoint runs its own JavaScript too, such as using JQuery: http://www.stephanrocks.com/2011/10/05/_spbodyonloadfunctionnames-in-sharepoint-vs-jquerys-document-ready/ ]

Comment: Thanks Elsa!! I agree with you on SPD usage...links found useful..I've tried something if option is selected 'All' then don't invoke SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns function otherwise invoke.. but it is not working...I think this is common scenario but struggling to achieve in sharepoint cascading.